# TeamCity - Specifying subfolder filter for pending changes

Tags: teamcity

Having just converted a lot (hundreds) of build configurations over to use Git instead of Subversion, I've hit an issue with how pending changes are managed / used by TeamCity. Before explaining the problem though, I need to explain the scenario to add context...

This is a very large legacy monolith codebase with a lot of projects and complicated dependencies. When using SVN, all of the build configs had a VCS root and overrode the 'checkout directory' to point to a particular subdirectory. All build configs checked out to the same *base* folder though, eg...

Build Config 1's checkout path: C:\Code\TheMonolith\Project1
Build Config 2's checkout path: C:\Code\TheMonolith\Project2\

The TeamCity build config dependencies are key, as some projects expect that other projects have already been built in that folder structure.

This worked okay for SVN.

Given for Git, it doesn't make sense to have different directories with different HEADs - I've changed all build configs' checkout directories to be the base path - ie. the Git repo root - eg. `C:\Code\TheMonolith\`, and set the "trigger rule" to be what the checkout path used to be in SVN. This gets us most of the way there.

The problem we're facing now is with snapshot dependencies and 'pending changes'. Because a build config's calculated "changes" are across the entire repo - it means that ALL snapshot dependencies are built for ANY change in Git. Ideally, we want to specify a subfolder that affects the pending changes - like we did with the trigger path.

The only other related setting I can see are the checkout rules. But from what I understand, this seems to be a workaround for Git where it checks out the entire repo, then deletes everything that doesn't match the checkout rule. Which for our scenario definitely isn't what we want.

Feels like I've hit a bit of a deadend with this, and the only hack I can think of to get around this is to add a new build step at the start of each build config, which uses the REST API to check for pending changes, and stop the build (with success status) if there are no pending changes within the trigger rule path. This feels very hacky, and a lot of work to implement across hundreds of build configs.

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: You are correct in your perception of how Checkout Rules work (at least in the sense that you are left with what "has not been deleted yet"). In short, Checkout Rules will limit the scope of the source files for the Build Configuration, and thus also limit how many "Changes" you see. You will only see changes if they modify contents within the limited scope defined by your Checkout Rule. The Trigger Rule is what starts your job.

This enables you to limit checkout as well as "Changes" to the defined scope, but to my knowledge that's where the fun ends. :/

Comment: Ps: I've had to create a script which will manually trigger the correct sub-project of a git repo, based on which sub-projects where updated. This allowed for more flexible and advanced triggering, at the cost of an increased pipeline complexity.